# How to a create a json blob format from json object

Tags: json, amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon Balance Load, I need to send a json object with a property sourceDetails that must be formatted as json blob.

```
"sourceDetails":"{\"institutionName\" : \"Fred Meyer\", \"institutionParentCompany\" : \"Kroger\", \"address1\" : \"2041 148th Ave NE\", \"address2\" : \"\", \"city\" : \"Bellevue\", \"state\" : \"Washington\", \"zip\" : \"98007\", \"phoneNumber\" : \"+14258658560\"}"
```

I have not found any information on how to do this, does any body have a clue on how to do this or any directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to jsonblob.com there you can create edit blob from Jason is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you running from lambda you can do the following using node js

```
    var sourceString = "'sourcedDetails':  {..json string..}"
    var blob = new Blob([sourcedDetails], {type : 'application/json'});
```